# Можно ли узнать размер реальной программы если в конец её исполняемого файла были дописаны другие данные?

Tags: c++, файлы

При нажатии пользователем на сайте кнопки "Скачать", PHP скрипт берёт с диска болванку установщика, написанного на C++, и дописывает ему в конец шифрованные персональные параметры пользователя (каждый раз новые, пароли меняются). При запуске установщик должен найти этот "хвост", расшифровать и инициализировать свои переменные полученными параметрами.

Сейчас для этой цели используется определённый строковый маркер в конце болванки, после которого и дописываются параметры, но маркер - крайне ненадёжная штука - он может случайным образом повториться в кодированных данных (теоретически это возможно) и... в результате `string.rfind()` будет не то смещение и в переменные запишется мусор...
Использовать точный размер изначального исполняемого файла для получения нужного смещения - беспроигрышный вариант, вот только как уже "испорченный" установщик поймёт сколько он весил перед добавлением "хвоста"?

Есть ли в C++ способ узнать размер реально рабочего кода? Или может по байтам можно понять куда в прочитанный в буфер с диска файл вписать его размер на момент `file_get_contents()` в php (объявив в болванке `int self_size`)?

Comment: Зависит от формата исполняемого файла. Обычно, да, можно.

Comment: @avp, формат - обычный exe, скомпилированный статически средствами MinGW

Comment: Запрос `exe файл формат` сразу приводит [сюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.EXE) (осталось изучить).

Comment: @avp, всё понял, формат PE! Изображения разбирал на части, а вот про экзешник не подумал, что там тоже заголовки есть - это меняет дело. Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Ну дописывайте сначала данные, а потом размер дописанного куска.

Comment: @VladD, это вообще шикарно! Просто 4 байта с размером в конце! И как я не додумался... Спасибо!

Comment: @Iceman: Пожалуйста!